# Java add text string to Rectangle2D

Tags: java, string

I have some rectangles. Given a rectangle declared and defined as:

```
Rectangle2D rec = new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

Is it possible to add a string of text inside this rectangle?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to fit a string into a predefined rectangle, consider using [`FontMetrics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) to find the bounds of the string. The `getStringBounds()` method is shown in this [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/6c3b8c8ba2653176) and illustrated below.

Addendum: Once you know the bounds, it's much easier to center the string in a larger rectangle or trim it to fit. ['HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS' (U+2026)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) is commonly used to signal the elision.

[image: FrameChars]

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a string within the bounds of the rectangle.

```
Graphics g = ...
...
...
String yourString = ...
...
...
g.drawString(yourString, rec.getX(), rec.getY());
```

Using [FontMetrics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) might prove useful for you.

Comment: You'll probably get it from the `paint(Graphics)` method you're using to paint your `Rectangle2D` or `Component.getGraphics()`

Comment: No -- Do not use Component.getGraphics() as the Graphics object obtained will not persist. Please read the graphics tutorials before trying to go further with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple resize method using this code :

```
package org.tw2.adaptedtext;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author util2
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResizedTextFrame rtf = new ResizedTextFrame();        
        rtf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ResizedTextFrame extends JFrame {
        String title = "2D resized text example";
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        Rectangle2D destRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 600, 200);

        Shape textInShape;
        double xText = 0, yText = 0;

        public ResizedTextFrame() throws HeadlessException {
            init();
        }

        private void init(){
            setSize(800, 600);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Force center screen
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // Get a shape for wanted settings
            textInShape = getTextInRectangle(title, font, destRect);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Get a 2D context
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

            // Storage
            AffineTransform oldTr = g2d.getTransform();

            // Set the background to white
            g2d.setColor(Color.white);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            //============================================================= Text
            // Settings
            AffineTransform atText = new AffineTransform();
            atText.setToTranslation(150 + xText, 150 + yText + destRect.getHeight());
            g2d.setTransform(atText);
            // Fill the text to red
            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.fill(textInShape);
            // Set the text outline to blue
            g2d.setColor(Color.blue);            
            g2d.draw(textInShape);
            // Restore
            g2d.setTransform(oldTr);
            //==================================================================

            //=========================================== Rectangle (boundaries)            
            // Settings
            AffineTransform atRect = new AffineTransform();
            atRect.setToTranslation(150, 150);
            g2d.setTransform(atRect);
            // Draw a rectangle around the text to green
            g2d.setColor(Color.green.darker());
            g2d.draw(destRect);            
            // Restore
            g2d.setTransform(oldTr);
            //==================================================================
        }

        public Shape getTextInRectangle(String text, Font font, Rectangle2D destRectangle){
            // Create a new image to get Graphics2D for measure
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

            // Create a FontRenderContext to prepare the calculation of elements of font
            FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();

            // Free graphics resources
            g2d.dispose();

            // Set the text
            TextLayout txt = new TextLayout(text, font, frc);

            // Get boundaries of text
            Rectangle2D textBounds = txt.getBounds();

            // Get percents (compare textBounds to destRectangle)
            double percentX = destRectangle.getWidth() / textBounds.getWidth();
            double percentY = destRectangle.getHeight() / textBounds.getHeight();

            // Define an aspect transform
            AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
            transform.setToScale(percentX, percentY);

            //-- Specials settings for location of text ------------------------
            xText = -txt.getBounds().getX() * percentX;
            yText = -txt.getDescent() * percentY;
            //------------------------------------------------------------------

            // Get the shape
            return txt.getOutline(transform);
        }
    }
}
```

The method to use is `Shape getTextInRectangle(String text, Font font, Rectangle2D destRectangle)`.

Example :
[image: adaptedtext]

Try by yourself!