# Why is this not drawing consistently?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, joptionpane

I wrote a quick test program that takes a string input and draws it on a JFrame. Super simple. But for some reason, the program isn't drawing consistently. As in, it doesn't always draw the string to the screen once the input is taken. To try and debug, I added a repaint(); to paintComponent (which repeatedly asked for an input to draw, hence why I added the double buffer). When the program decided not to draw to the frame, it didn't make it to repaint(); and a new input dialog didn't show up. I'm having trouble understanding why.

```
package test;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

public Main() {
    setTitle("Test Project");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString(input(), 140, 130);
}

public static String input() {
    String x = ((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
        null, "Enter a string", "Test Project",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null, null, null));
    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

}
}
```

One note: initially, the input method was in a separate class, because that's where it will be in the project I'm testing this for. I moved it here for sake of brevity and because the problem still popped up no matter where the method was.

Comment: Use a `JPanel` to draw on, which is `Double Buffered` by default, and override it's `paintComponent()` method, instead of drawing on the `JFrame` :-) Moreover please, don't try to be over-smart, change the state somewhere else and call `repaint()` from that location, instead of `asking for/changing` the state from within the `paintComponent()` method :-) In other words, try to take `String` value somewhere else, and immediately call `repaint()` to make the new state visible. Instead of blocking the painting procedure, by invoking a modal `JOptionPane`...

Comment: I just have one question, the documentation for paint() makes it seem like repaint HAS to be called from within paintComponent, paintBorder or paintChildren. To be fair to the question, it's probably important to mention that I'm new to Swing and awt and that I'm fairly new to Java. I'm just trying to figure out what works with what and what is essentially silly to do.

Comment: Please refer this Java Tutorials regarding [Solving Common Painting Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html), the first problem and solution to the same will answer your question in the most appropriate sense :-) And no, `repaint()` is not to be called from inside the `paintComponent()`, instead `paint()` itself calls `paintComponent()` along with `paintBorder() and paintChildren()` methods. Adding `repaint()` inside `paintComponent()` will lead to recursive behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take theory from my comment :-)

Adding more points to my comments :

- Instead of using `setSize()` on the `JFrame`, instead override `getPreferredSize()` method, for any `JComponent/JPanel` you extending. Now simply call `pack()` on the `JFrame`, for it to calculate it's own size.
- Please read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Here is working example, of what I am saying :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    private JButton button; 
    private String message;

    private ActionListener buttonAction = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            message = input();
            repaint();
        }
    };

    public Main() {
        message = "Nothing to display yet...";
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        button = new JButton("Get Message");
        button.addActionListener(buttonAction);

        contentPane.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(message, 50, 50);
    }

    public String input() {
        String x = ((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
                null, "Enter a string", "Test Project",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                        null, null, null));
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

### EDIT 1 :

If you do not like the use of `JButton` for asking input, you can add a `MouseListener` to the `JPanel` on which you drawing, as shown in the below example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    private String message;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    private MouseAdapter mouseAction = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            message = input();
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    };

    public Main() {
        message = "Nothing to display yet...";
        x = y = 0;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        addMouseListener(mouseAction);
        contentPane.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(message, x, y);
    }

    public String input() {
        String x = ((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
                null, "Enter a string", "Test Project",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                        null, null, null));
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Occasionally that second code will only update the text if you resize it. That only happens if the string runs past the screen, but damn. I learned more from this then from the explanations in documentation. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JaimeWissner : You can refer to this wonderful post by @trashgod, regarding the use of [getStringBounds()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785229/1057230), that might can give you a slight idea, how to restrict sending `String` outside the bounds of the current window :-) For the rest, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are so many things wrong with your code that I wrote a new program to do the same thing you wanted.  I did keep your input method.

I suggest you spend a good bit of time studying the [Oracle Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleInput implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("String Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(new DisplayRunnable(drawingPanel)).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleInput());
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 7580353846463376668L;

        private String text;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
            this.text = " ";
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
            TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(text, g.getFont(), frc);
            Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();

            int width = (int) Math.round(bounds.getWidth());
            int height = (int) Math.round(bounds.getHeight());
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = height + (getHeight() - height) / 2;

            layout.draw(g2d, (float) x, (float) y);
        }

    }

    public class DisplayRunnable implements Runnable {

        private String displayString = " ";

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        public DisplayRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long sleep = 5L;

            while ((displayString != null) && (!displayString.equals(""))) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        drawingPanel.setText(displayString);
                        drawingPanel.repaint();
                    }   
                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }


                displayString = input();
                sleep = 3000L;
            }

        }

        public String input() {
            String x = ((String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(drawingPanel,
                    "Enter a string", "Test Project", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, null, null));
            return x;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code has the same problem mine had. It will occasionally not update. The only difference I have found between this and mine, is that yours will keep the last string drawn instead of clearing the screen. Though, this did show me how to run the input box relative to the frame, so thank you for that.

Comment: @Jaime Wissner: Sorry about that.  When I tested the code, it updated the drawing every time.

Comment: Well, maybe it's my computer then. Hmm.

Comment: @Jaime Wissner: Having some time to think about it, I do an invokeLater to update the drawing.  Most times (almost all the time), the drawing is done way before the 3 second Timer is up.  I suppose in some cases it might not.  I hesitate to use the invokeAndWait method, because it's usually not necessary.  I can't imagine what would hold up the repaint for 3 seconds.